# Finding duplicates through 3 columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame (short sample)

```
           EIN  file_num  year
0     46012492       838  2017
1     46012492      1790  2016
2     46012492      3757  2015
3     46012492      4536  2014
4     46012492      6187  2013
..         ...       ...   ...
559  980634789      5095  2015
560  980634789      5653  2014
561  980634789      5800  2014
562  980634789      6750  2013
563  980634789      8133  2012
```

I need to get rid of files that have the same EIN and same year. So for example, you can see row 560 and 561 contain files with EIN `980634789` and from year `2014`. I need to delete one of these (doesn't really matter which but preferably the one with the smallest `file_num`.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates).

If you don't care about which one to keep:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["EIN", "year"])
```

---

If you care about to keep the smallest file_num:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["file_num"])
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["EIN", "year"], keep="first")
```

Comment: This works well, thank you. Can you just edit your code for future users, you have a small mistake: `df = df.sort_values(by="[file_num]")` should be `df = df.sort_values(by="file_num")`With no square brackets

Answer (score 1):

First you need to [sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) followed by [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(["EIN", "file_num", "year"]) # default sorting in ascending
df = df.drop_duplicates(["EIN", "year"])
```